# Symfony2's Doctrine does not create one-to-many structure for me

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables. First table is `users` and second is `datas`. Datas has `useridx` column which is foreign with `user`'s `idx`. (*primary unique key*).

These are the table structures:

Table `users`

```
CREATE TABLE public.users (
  idx       bigint NOT NULL,
  "name"    varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  surname   varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  isactive  boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (idx), 
  CONSTRAINT users_idx_key
    UNIQUE (idx)
) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  );
```

Table `datas`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.datas (
  idx       bigint NOT NULL,
  useridx   bigint,
  phrase    varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  response  varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT datas_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (idx), 
  CONSTRAINT datas_idx_key
    UNIQUE (idx),
  /* Foreign keys */
  CONSTRAINT fk_cf180c1a262768b5
    FOREIGN KEY (useridx)
    REFERENCES public.users(idx)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  );
```

Now when i run these commands:

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml
./src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm
--from-database
--force
```

And;

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeDemoBundle annotation
app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle
```

I got this result:

**Datas.php**

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Datas
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="datas")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Datas
{
    /**
     * @var bigint $idx
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idx", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="datas_idx_seq", allocationSize="1", initialValue="1")
     */
    private $idx;

    /**
     * @var string $phrase
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phrase", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phrase;

    /**
     * @var string $response
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="response", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $response;

    /**
     * @var Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="useridx", referencedColumnName="idx")
     * })
     */
    private $useridx;



    /**
     * Get idx
     *
     * @return bigint 
     */
    public function getIdx()
    {
        return $this->idx;
    }

    /**
     * Set phrase
     *
     * @param string $phrase
     */
    public function setPhrase($phrase)
    {
        $this->phrase = $phrase;
    }

    /**
     * Get phrase
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhrase()
    {
        return $this->phrase;
    }

    /**
     * Set response
     *
     * @param string $response
     */
    public function setResponse($response)
    {
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    /**
     * Get response
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
    }

    /**
     * Set useridx
     *
     * @param Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Users $useridx
     */
    public function setUseridx(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Users $useridx)
    {
        $this->useridx = $useridx;
    }

    /**
     * Get useridx
     *
     * @return Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUseridx()
    {
        return $this->useridx;
    }
}
?>
```

**Users.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var bigint $idx
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idx", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="users_idx_seq", allocationSize="1", initialValue="1")
     */
    private $idx;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string $surname
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var boolean $isactive
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="isactive", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isactive;

    /**
     * Get idx
     *
     * @return bigint 
     */
    public function getIdx()
    {
        return $this->idx;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set surname
     *
     * @param string $surname
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set isactive
     *
     * @param boolean $isactive
     */
    public function setIsactive($isactive)
    {
        $this->isactive = $isactive;
    }

    /**
     * Get isactive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsactive()
    {
        return $this->isactive;
    }
}
?>
```

I also have yml files but i dont think they are necessary in here only PHP files i posted here.

Now, when i run this command inside of my controller:

```
<?php

$user = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Users')
->find(24);

$phrase = $user->getDatas()->getPhrase();

?>
```

I got an error that say `Call to a member function getDatas() on a non-object...`. I know it is clear. In Users.php i don't have getDatas().

But what i read from Symfony2 and Doctrine documentation is it should be there because they are related. All i want to do is get Datas inside of Users.

What is my mistake here? What im missing?

**Update**:
I added this lines to the `Users.php`

```
<?php
/**
     * @var \Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Datas
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Datas", mappedBy="datas", cascade={"all"})
     */
     private $datas;
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->datas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add phrases
     *
     * @param Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Datas $datas
     */
    public function addPhrases(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Datas $datas)
    {
        $this->datas[] = $datas;
    }

    /**
     * Get datas
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDatas()
    {
        return $this->datas;
    }
?>
```

And these lines to the `Datas.php`

```
<?php
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="users", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $users;
/**
     * Set users
     *
     * @param Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Users $users
     */
    public function setUsers(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Users $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Users 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
?>
```

Now `getDatas()` is working but inside of it is not. (`$user->getDatas()->getPhrase();`)
I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection::getPhrase()
```

**Conclusion**: I got collection error because it returns a collection -of course-. Iterate (like foreach) it and you will access the data. (If you encounter a problem like this.)

Comment: That's just a guess, but have you checked if "Datas" is an allowed name with doctrine?

Comment: @hakre i don't understand what you mean but everything is just working. For example if i want to add a record to the users i can assign datas and datas also added to the database without an error. But, when i want to fetch them i got this error. (Now i will try another name and way to do it)

Comment: That was just a quick guess. I know that some names can not be used that easily that's all. I don't know if that is the actual cause of your issue technically. So that's just guessing by me.

Comment: @hakre ah i got it now. No, i did renaming on table. Not worked either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If look at the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn) of `@JoinColumn`

*This annotation is **used in the context of relations in @ManyToOne, @OneToOne fields** and **in the Context of @JoinTable nested inside a @ManyToMany**. This annotation is not required. If its not specified the attributes name and referencedColumnName are inferred from the table and primary key names.*

So as you are using `ManyToOne` relation your relation definition would be,

```
/**
 * @var Users
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="useridx", referencedColumnName="idx")
 */
private $useridx;
```

**Edit:**

If you want to get datas from user side then you have to create [OneToMany](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) relation. e.g

In Datas.php

```
/**
 * @var Users
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy = "datas")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="useridx", referencedColumnName="idx")
 */
private $useridx;
```

And  in Users.php add following line,

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Datas", mappedBy="useridx", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $datas;
```

And then do a `doctrine:generate:entities` command. To do operations on relation check [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) doc entry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already did this (as you can see in my Datas.php). The fact is i have to fetch two tables in one select. To be more clear, when i get User from Users table i want to also fetch Datas that related to this user (lets say useridx = 1). In your example (which is same as with mine) i only get User 1 from Users table. I had to fetch Datas table at the same time using $user->getDatas()->getPhrase();

Comment: `$user->getDatas()` returns a [Collection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html) object. You have to iterate through the collection to get phrases of each collection

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see the collection(!). It is working properly. Answer is accepted.